# git-svn: How do I sync to an svn revision?

Tags: git, svn

I have a cloned git-svn repo. Using "git svn rebase" will get me latest revision of svn, but how do I get an svn revision like I do with "svn update -rXXXXX"?

## EDIT:

What I meant is to update to an upstream svn revision as opposed to a local git change set.

## Update:

I accepted Greg Hewgill's answer, although the real solution is in his comments, as following steps:

1. git svn rebase
2. git log, and find commit ID that is between the local svn revision before Step 1 and latest upstream svn revision.
3. git checkout commitID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find out which Git commit identifier corresponds to the Subversion revision you are interested in (`git log` can help here), and then use `git checkout` to check out that commit.

Comment: "git log" seems to just show me the revisions up to last time i "git svn rebase". What if I'm behind upstream svn repo and want to sync to a revision that I don't see in git log? e.g., if head of my git log is 22222, but upstream now is 33333, and I want to sync to 30000?

Comment: I just edited my comment. That's my scenario. I don't see beyond svn revision 22222 in my git log.

Comment: Just use `git svn rebase` to update to the latest code, then `git checkout` to go back to the revision you want to be at. There isn't any way (or any need) to tell Git to rebase only up to some specific Subversion revision number.

Answer (score 1):

`git-svn` creates one commit for every revision. You can use `git checkout <branch> <commit-id>` to check out that commit.

You can use `git log` to find the appropriate commit, especiall with the `grep` flag:
`--grep=<pattern>
    Limit the commits output to ones with log message that matches the 
    specified pattern (regular expression).`

This is important because the revision should be in the commit message that git-svn creates.

Comment: "git log" seems to just show me the revisions up to last time i "git svn rebase". What if I'm behind upstream svn repo and want to sync to a revision that I don't see in git log? e.g., if head of my git log is 22222, but upstream now is 33333, and I want to sync to 30000?

Comment: Rebase first to get all revisions, then checkout the one you want.